# The probability of a white car with two airbags being a Jaguar

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> Assume that the car lot contains 30% Jaguars, 45% BMWs, and 25% Corvettes. Of the Jaguars, 60% have two airbags, 30% of the BMWs have two airbags, and 20% of the Corvettes have two airbags. Furthermore, 90% of the Jaguars, 70% of the BMWs, and 30% of the Corvettes are white. The property of being white is independent from having two airbags. You are assigned a car at random.
>
> If the car has two airbags and is white, what is the probability that it is a Jaguar?

I have been working on this forever and  I keep getting for the final answer $.324$ over $.324+.0945+.015$ and the system keeps telling me I'm wrong. Please rescue me!

Comment: Hint: use bayes theorem

Answer (score 1):

I think you almost have it.  I guess your $.324$ came from probability of Jaguar and Two and White, and hence should be $(.30)(.60)(.90)=.162$.  I think your other numbers are ok.